# Find Jordan form of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ -5 &-3 & -7 \\  1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) $$

I figured out the eigenvalues are all -1 from the characteristic polynomial, but I'm not sure how to find the 1's on the subdiagonal. I know they're 1, but I'm not sure how that's determined. I also know that the eigenspace is 0 on the matrix where we subtract -1 on the diagonal. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to know only the Jordan normal form or also the basis with respect to which the matrix is in JNF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to find the minimal polynomial, in this case:

We know that the characteristic polynomial is going to be $(x+1)^3$.  The minimal polynomial must divide that.

We find
$$
A + I = \pmatrix{1&1&2\\-5&-2&-7\\1&0&1}
$$

**Method 1:** what is $(A+I)^2$?  If it's zero, the min polynomial is $(x+1)^2$.  Otherwise, it's $(x+1)^3$

**Method 2:** It is pretty clear that rank$(A + I) \geq 2$.  Of the possible Jordan forms $J$, only one satisfies rank$(J+I) = 2$.

Comment: Thanks, I used method 1 on my exam today.

Comment: It should be $-2$, not $-4$, on term $a_{22}$.

Answer (score 4):

I will map it out and you can fill in the details.

**Approach 1:**

We are given:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ -5 &-3 & -7 \\  1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Setting up and solving

$$|A - \lambda I| = 0 \implies -(\lambda + 1)^3 = 0 \implies \lambda_{1,2,3} = -1$$

To find the eigenvectors, we would take $[A - \lambda_i I] = 0$, assuming we have unique eigenvalues. Here we do not. Do you know how to determine the algebraic versus geometric multiplicity?

We attempt to the find the first eigenvector using $[A + I]v_1 = 0$ and the row-reduced-echelon-form (RREF) produces:

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\  1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Unfortunately, we cannot generate anymore linearly independent eigenvectors ($\dim ker(A)=1$), so have to resort to generalized eigenvectors.

To find the second (generalized) eigenvectors, we set up and solve $[A + I]v_2 = v_1$, and after finding the RREF yields:

$$v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\  0 \end{pmatrix} $$

To find the third (generalized) eigenvectors, we set up and solve $[A + I]v_3 = v_2$, and after finding the RREF yields:

$$v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\  0 \end{pmatrix} $$

We can use these eigenvectors to form $P$ as:

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

We can now use this to find our Jordan matrix $J$ as:

$$J = P^{-1} A P = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

**Approach 2:**

Have you learned about the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomials and ways to infer the Jordan form?

You can find discussions in previous MSE posts like [How can one find Jordan forms, given the characteristic and minimal polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359136/how-can-one-find-jordan-forms-given-the-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomials), [Jordan normal form for a characteristic polynomial $(x-a)^5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576139/jordan-normal-form-for-a-characteristic-polynomial-x-a5?rq=1), and these [*lecture notes*](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Efoucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect4.pdf).

Try stepping through these [*whimsical notes*](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/Linear_Algebra/Min-Poly_and_JNF.pdf) and see if you can work through approach 2.

Comment: Thanks, I used the minimum polynomial to show it wasn't annilihated on my exam today.